# Why does $P(\max(X,Y)\leq x) = P(X\le x \ \cap \ Y\le x)$ involve intersection and not union?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Show that the Gumbel distribution is max stable, i.e. if $X$ and $Y$
>   are two independent Gumbel distributed random variables with the same
>   scale parameter, then $\max(X,Y)$ is Gumbel with the same scale
>   parameter as $X$ and $Y$ . Recall that the distribution function in
>   the Gumbel distribution is
>
> $$F(x) = \exp(−e^{−(x−b)/a}),$$
>
> where $a$ is the scale parameter.

**Solution:** If $X$ and $Y$ are independent and Gumbel distributed with scale parameter $a$ and location parameters $b_1$ and $b_2$ respectively and $Z=\max(X,Y)$ then

$$P(Z\le x)=P(X\le x)P(Y\le x)=\exp\left(-e^{-(x-b_1)/a}-e^{-(x-b_2)/a}\right)= \\ = \exp\left(-e^{-x/a}(e^{b_1/a}+e^{b_2/a})\right).$$

Since $e^{b_1/a}+e^{b_2/a}$ is positive and $e^{c/a}$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$  there has to exist a $c:e^{b_1/a}+e^{b_2/a}=e^{c/a}.$

---

**Questions:** I don't understand how they treat the $\max$-function here. How does this apply:

$$P(Z\le x)=P(X\le x)P(Y\le x)?$$

This has to mean that $$P(Z\le x)=P(\max(X,Y)\leq x)=P(X\le x)P(Y\le x),$$

but then how is $$P(\max(X,Y)\leq x)=P(X\le x)P(Y\le x)?$$

I understand that the independency is responible for the multiplication, but what happens with the $\max(X,Y)?$

Let's assume that $X>Y,$ then it follows that

$$P(\max(X,Y)\leq x)=P(Y\le x),$$

If the reveres is true, i.e if $Y > X$ then it follows that

$$P(\max(X,Y)\leq x)=P(X\le x),$$

I don't see how these end upp being multiplied. I suppose that what I want is that

$$P(\max(X,Y)\leq x) = P(X\le x \ \cap \ Y\le x)=P(X\le x)P(Y\le x).$$

But why is it an intersection and not a union? Only one of the two cases can happen, so either $X>Y$ OR $X<Y$, and in probability, OR = $\cup$ and not $\cap.$ Can anyone explain why this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement
$$P(\max(X,Y)\leq x) = P(X\le x \ \cap \ Y\le x)\tag1 $$
involves an intersection because the event in the LHS is the same as the event in the RHS: If $x$ and $y$ are numbers, then $\max(x,y)\le c$ exactly when $x\le c$ **and** $y\le c$.  (Convince yourself that $\max(x,y)\le c$ is not the same as $x\le c$ **or** $y\le c$.)

Your line of reasoning fails because the statement
$$P(\max(X,Y)\leq x)=P(Y\le x)\tag2 $$
isn't true; the event in the LHS is not the same as the event in the RHS. I know you are arguing by cases, but the probability function $P(\cdot)$ is unaware of that. When you are arguing by cases, you need to *insert the case into the probability computation*, so that the events on LHS and RHS remain equal. The proper statement for case $X\le Y$ is:
$$P(\max(X,Y)\leq x\cap X\le Y)=P(Y\le x\cap X\le Y),\tag3 $$
because the events are now equal. Argue as follows: "If the max is less than or equal to $x$, and $X\le Y$, then $Y\le x$ and $X\le Y$. Conversely, if $X\le Y$ and $Y\le x$, then the max is less than or equal to $x$, and $X\le Y$." Yes, it's clunky, but without the qualifier $X\le Y$, you're back at (2) and the two sides of (2) are not equal.

The problem now is that (3) is a true statement but you haven't got yourself any closer to (1). You can rescue the computation, by taking it one step further:
$$P(\max(X,Y)\leq x\cap X\le Y)=P(Y\le x\cap X\le Y)=P(X\le x\cap Y\le x\cap X\le Y),\tag4 $$
again because the events are equal. Now write the version for case $X>Y$:

$$P(\max(X,Y)\le x\cap X> Y)=P(X\le x\cap X> Y)=P(X\le x\cap Y\le x\cap X> Y),\tag5 $$
and now add (4) and (5) together:
$$P(\max(X,Y)\le x)=P(X\le x\cap Y\le x).\tag6$$
In this last step (adding the two previous equalities), we are using the fact:
$$P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^c)=P(A).$$

Comment: Thank you. But what about this as equation (1):  $$P(\max(X,Y)\leq x) = P(X\le x, Y\le x) = P(X\le x \ \cap \ Y\le x)\tag1 $$ since we need the probability for both events (joint event) at the same time?

Comment: @Parseval These are the same thing. The convention is that using a comma to separate events is equivalent to using $\cap$.

Comment: Ok, but the consensus here is to always enterpret a max function as an "AND" statement?

Comment: @Parseval Specifically, the statement "$\max(x,y)\le c$" is equivalent to "$x\le c$ and $y\le c$".

Comment: @Parseval ... but you cannot make a similar "and" statement with $\ge$.

Comment: Would then $\max(X,Y)\ge c$ change my (1) to $$1-P(X\le x,Y \le x)?$$

Comment: @Parseval Almost. The analog is $P(\max(X,Y)\ge x)=1-P(X<x,Y<x)$. (Need to be careful with $\le$ vs $<$)

Comment: I thought there is no distinction between $<$ and $\le$ in the continous case? And why did we use $\le$ in the case of $\max(X,Y)\le c$ and $<$ for the case $\max(X,Y)\ge c$?

Comment: @Parseval The distinction between $\le$ vs $<$ pertains to logical equivalence of events.  The distinction makes a difference to the probability in the discrete case, but not in the continuous case.  Note: also true is $P(\max(X,Y)>x)=1-P(X\le x, Y\le x)$.

Answer (score 2):

If $X>Y,$ then the event that $X$ and $Y$ are *both* $\le x$ is *not* the same as the event that $Y\le x.$

For example, if $x = 3$ and $X=2$ and $Y=1,$ then the event that $X$ and $Y$ are both $\le x$ occurs.

But if $X=3$ and $x=2$ and $Y=1,$ then you have $X>Y$ and $Y\le x,$ but the event that $\max\{X,Y\}\le x$ does not occur.

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to quote and continue your line of thoughts

> ... but what happens with the $\max(X,Y)$?
>
> Let's assume that $X>Y$, then it follows that $(Y < \color{magenta}{Z = X)}$

$$P(\max(X,Y)\leq x) = P(Y < \color{magenta}{Z = X}\leq x) = P(Y\le x) \color{magenta}{\cdot P(X\le x)}$$

As highlighted in magenta, $X$ is still involved.

The same goes for the other case $Y>X$.

Comment: I don't understand that at all. Why is $X$ still involved and why is $$P(Y < \color{magenta}{Z = X}\leq x) = P(Y\le x) \color{magenta}{\cdot P(X\le x)}?$$ I've not seen a notation like $$P(A=B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)$$ in the entire course nor in the 600 page litterature I'm using. what I have seen is this $$P(A \cap B)=P(A,B)=P(A)\cdot P(B),$$ if the events $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Comment: @Parseval I never meant anything like $P(A=B)=P(A)⋅P(B)$. The highlight is for the logical-and. It's pretty common to state "$a<b$ and $b<c$" as just $a<b<c$. This is just a very simple thing so I didn't make a big deal out of it.

Comment: Thank you, I now see what you intended to say!

Comment: @Parseval Actually I should thank you for being so generous. I misjudged the situation and wasn't specific enough when I made the post.

Comment: Don't worry, any student moderately good at math would have understood your point, however I need some extra time and a few more explanations to fully grasp things.